# What's the measure of the segment $PD$ in the triangle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:- In the triangle $ABC$: $AB = 7, BC = 9$ and
$\angle B = 74^o$. The angle bisector of B intersects
the perpendicular bisector of AC in P. Calculate $PD$; if $AC \cap BP = D$.
(Answer:$3,7$)

My progress:

[image]
$P \in $ circumscribed circle $\triangle ABC \implies$

$ABCD$ is cyclic

$B$ is angle bissector $\implies AP = CP$

Ptolemy's Th:

$AB.CP+BC.AP = BP.AC \implies\\
7CP+9AP = AC.BP \therefore 
\boxed{16CP = AC.BP}$

Angle Bissector Th.:

$\frac{AD}{7} = \frac{CD}{9} \implies \frac{AD}{CD} = \frac{7}{9}$

Using formula for the length of angle bisector

$BD^2 =7.9-AD.DC =63-AD.DC$

Comment: Quite a few $3:4:5$ triangles. Drop a perp from $F$ to $AP$. Can you find $AP$ in terms of $R$ where $R$ is circumradius? Then use perp from $P$ to $AC$ find $AC$. Then apply Ptolemy to find $BP$. Using angle bisector find $AD$ and then $DM$ where $M$ is midpoint of $AC$. Finally knowing $PM$ and $DM$ will give you $PD$. This is just one approach. You can come up with other solutions too knowing the ratio of sides in some of the given triangles.

Comment: THanks for hint..I'll try

Comment: @MathLover  I managed to find all the segments m as a function of R but I still haven't found the value of R or another relation that gives the numerical value of BD and that would end the problem. $AD=\frac{21R}{25}, PM = \frac{18R}{25}, DM = \frac{3R}{25}$ and $BP=10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using power of point $D$, $AD \cdot DC = BD \cdot DP$. So your last equation can be rearranged to give
$$BD \cdot BP = 63$$
from which it is easy to work out $DP=BP-BD$.